# Save dynamic created form's data with Angular in PHP

Tags: angularjs

I have created a Dynamic form and it's working fine. All fields are coming from the database: Let say I have two values in my following form: firstname and lastname:

```
<form>

    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">

       <div ng-if="field.required == 'yes'">                

          <label>
            {{ field.fieldlabel }}
          </label>


        <input type = "{{ field.fieldtype }}" ng-model="values[$index]">



       </div>        

    </div>  

     <div id ="entryform-button">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" id="save" name="submit" value = "Save" ng-click="insertTrans()">
     </div>

</form>
```

But I am stuck at point where I am trying to save data into another table.

In angular, my code is as below:

```
$scope.values = []; 

    $scope.insertTrans = function () {

        console.log($scope.values);


    }
```

If i put Apple in the first input box and banana in the second input box, then I am getting following output in my console:

0: "Apple" ​ 1: "Banana" ​ length: 2

Can anyone direct me how to get proper data to be saved into database table: like firstname = apple and lastname = banana

Please note that user can create more fields into database such as email and password and date fields etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not told AngularJS what those names should be. You are only naming them with the numbers of `$index`. You must provide a field identifier in your data. You can use the `fieldLabel`:

```
<input type = "{{ field.fieldtype }}" ng-model="values[field.fieldLabel]">
```

but it would be ideal to create a unique identifier for the field, like `fieldId`, and your `fieldId` needs to be unique across your form, and preferrebly all one case (upper or lower) like `"username"`, and `"password"`. So, now your data will look like this:

username: "Apple" ​ password: "Banana" ​ length: 2

Comment: Can you also give me an idea, how can I get this array into php.... like i have unique id which is firstname: "Apple" lastname: "Banana" which is now easily pass to php..... but now i want Apple to be saved in firstname field and Banana to be saved in lastname field.... again I cannot hardcode firstname and lastname as i don't know how many fields end user will create and what are the names of those fields....

Comment: You could convert it to a JSON string very easily to send with as a POST request to PHP. `JSON.stringify($scope.values)`

Comment: Thank you @Pop-A-Stash. I have tried JSON.stringify($scope.values); but it didn't work.... Can you check my following code and let me know what is my mistake in catching and inserting data in php:                  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);                                                                           echo $data;